# How can I read PDFs in scrolling mode on an iPad 2?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, pdf

I bought a used iPad 2, mainly for reading. After a short while I found out that it won't run a more recent iOS than 9.3.5 and that there are basically no apps that run on this iOS version (rendering the iPad 2 almost unuseable--I really couldn't believe it). I have been able to open PDFs with the iBooks app that came with it, but I don't like the way you have to swipe from right to left on the screen to get to the next page. Is there either a way to switch to a "scrolling" behaviour in iBooks, where you can just swipe up and down on the screen to move seamlessly between pages, or a PDF viewer app that supports this *and* can still be installed on iOS 9.3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a solution - please give feedback so I can correct.

Login with the same appleid on a more modern apple device (iphone etc) or possibly on a desktop computer.

Purchase (for zero dollars) the apps "USB disk" with the purple logo and  "Adobe Acrobat".

On the ipad 2, open App Store and either look at "Purchased Apps" or browse to find the identical apps you already "bought", and download them.

The option to download an older version should appear.

The abovementioned apps have a version that works under 9.3.5 on ipad 2, open .pdf and use vertical scrolling. I just checked!

I also recommend you get the Chrome browser at the same time as some websites will work with it when Safari will not, and its availability may be terminated...

Comment: It works! Thanks so much. I was finally able to borrow an older but not too old iPhone from a friend which I could reset and use with my Apple ID. Why all this? It boggles the mind. Never going to buy another product by this company that's for sure. Now I still haven't been able to transfer a PDF...

Comment: Just search stackexchange, then put this question formally. Or use dropbox, or google drive with gmail.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up sending all needed files via Mail. Had to download every single one on its own, and to specific apps though. Why not just connect a cable and be able to Copy/Paste into a directory? Why? Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread in 2024. The solution still works, partially. Thanks! I have a factory-reset iPad 2 iOS 9.3.5, and it now runs Acrobat Reader.

As suggested, I also downloaded the last compatible version of Chrome. The app runs, but Google won’t sign me in because the old Chrome doesn’t have the current security features. It says I must update to the latest version (not possible).